# Nodemon + gulpfile + browsersync

Tags: typescript, gulp, browser-sync, nodemon

Even if there is a lot of tutorials in a web I found it difficult to configure Nodemon + gulpfile + browsersync. I modified my views which are written in .pug as well as stylesheets which are written in .scss to find whether Browser-sync refresh a browser. Sadly it didn't.

I tried to succeed by following these links:

1. [It does not refresh my browser.](https://gist.github.com/sogko/b53d33d4f3b40d3b4b2e)
2. [Tried two last methods it does not refresh my browser either.](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/a-browsersync-primer)
3. [It did not help me much.](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/392)

My server is listening at port 5000.

**This is how my gulpfile.ts looks like:**

```
import * as gulp from "gulp";
import * as sass from "gulp-sass";
import * as plumber from "gulp-plumber";
import * as prefix from "gulp-autoprefixer";
import * as nodemon from "gulp-nodemon";
import * as browsersync from "browser-sync";

const options = {
    pug: {
        "pretty": true
    },

    styles: {
        style: { outputStyle: "expanded" },
        src: "public/stylesheets/*.scss",
        prefixer: {
            browsers: ["last 10 versions"],
            cascade: false
        },
    }
};

gulp.task("serve", () => {
    browsersync({
        proxy: "localhost:8000",
        open: false
    });

});

gulp.task("nodemon", () => {
    nodemon({
        script: "server.ts",
        ext: "ts",
        execMap: {
            "ts": "ts-node"
        }
    }).on("restart", () => {
        browsersync.reload();
    });
})

gulp.task("styles", () => {
    let opt = options.styles;
    gulp.src(opt.src).
        pipe(sass(options.styles.style).on("error", sass.logError)).
        pipe(prefix(opt.prefixer)).
        pipe(gulp.dest("public/stylesheets"));
});

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    gulp.watch("public/stylesheets/*.scss", ["styles"]);
});


gulp.task("default", ["styles", "serve", "nodemon", "watch"]);
```

**My question is:**
What I have to change in my code to accomplish fully workable nodemon and browsersync?
I did a research and I am sure that nodemon works fine.